# Removing an anchor tag surrounding selected images in jquery

Tags: jquery

I have a piece of code that, when the page loads, checks through a series of images and sees whether their id contains the word video.

If it does, I want to be able to remove the anchor tag surrounding the image. However, teh way that I am currently doing this (through .remove()) removes the image as it is within the anchor tag I'm removing.

Is there a way of just removing the anchor tag?
NOTE: the list of images will be pulled in based on the user accessing them, so it won't be pre-determined code that can be appended in.

CODE:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('ul.thumbnails li a img').each(function() {
        if($(this).attr('id').indexOf('video') != -1){
            var $parent = $(this).closest('a');
            $parent.remove();
        } else {
            $(this).addClass('photo');
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: perhaps the unwrap() function - http://api.jquery.com/unwrap/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using [jQuery unwrap](http://api.jquery.com/unwrap/):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('ul.thumbnails li a img').each(function() {
        if($(this).attr('id').indexOf('video') != -1){
            $(this).unwrap();
        } else {
            $(this).addClass('photo');
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: I didn't know about unwrap either! Thanks very much. replaceWith($parent.contents()) also worked so thanks to both who contributed those!

Answer (score 0):

the problem is your anchor tag contains your image so when you remove you anchor you also remove the image inside it. Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('ul.thumbnails li a img').each(function() {
        if($(this).attr('id').indexOf('video') != -1){
            var $parent = $(this).closest('a');
            $parent.replaceWith($(this).html());
        } else {
            $(this).addClass('photo');
        }
    });
});
```

So I'm replacing the anchor tag with the image tag, rather than removing the anchor

Answer (score 0):

When you remove an element, all its children are also removed. Therefore you would need to clone and append the image first. Consider using the clone function, especially when you need to maintain event handlers.

Try:

```
$(this).closest('li').append($(this).clone());
```

before you remove the $parent.